# Please help identify this LEGO set that has owls and snakes?

Tags: set-identification, pick-a-brick

[image]

I cannot identify this LEGO set my grandma gave to me.  I want to help her build it for my cousin, but my grandma did not have the instructions.

Answer (score 18):

That white snake appears in [two sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=98136&colorID=1&in=A), and in quantity either one or two. My best guess is that it was from a Pick-a-Brick wall at a Lego Store, or something very similar. I'm basing this on the many, many repeated pieces.